# windows linux subsystem explorer.exe

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

so the new windows subsystem (2019 Windows 10 April Release) for Linux is out and my ubuntu subsystem was upgraded.
I'm supposed to be able to open the Linux folder in my windows explorer but I'm not getting the correct folders when I run the command.

```
falieson@firefly:~$ explorer.exe ~/
```

Opens the windows user's My Documents folder.

```
falieson@firefly:~$ explorer.exe .
```

Opens C:\Windows\System32

My only guess is that when I did the windows install for GitHub desktop and opted into a Linux-ification of my shell it borked this upgrade from Windows.

Thanks for your ideas to resolve this.

Comment: [Where is the Ubuntu directory in Windows?](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/77jf39/where_is_the_ubuntu_directory_in_windows/).  Pay your attention to the [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) article.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible as mentioned in JosefZ comment.

If you have the latest Windows Insider Preview, or you can wait until the next Windows release, that changes as described in the [WSL Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2019/02/15/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/)